# Capturing the screenshot of the url

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, phantomjs

I am capturing the screenshot of the URL through phantomjs.

I performed it using phantomjs driver but capturing one screenshot is taking around 2sec.

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('path/to/phantomjs.exe')
def driver_initialize(width,height):
  driver.set_script_timeout(30)
  if width and height:
        driver.set_window_size(width, height)


def driver_screenshot(urls):
  green_color=[]
  for i in urls:
    print(i)
    filename = i.split("/")[4] + ".png"
    screen_path =  os.path.join(path, filename)
    images.append(screen_path)
    driver.get(i)
    driver.save_screenshot(screen_path)


def driver_quit():
  driver.quit()

driver_initialize(1024,768)
driver_screenshot(links)
driver_quit()
```

With this code, each screenshot capturing and saving process is taking approx 3-4 sec. I need to process 1million urls. How can I optimize this code?

Comment: phantomjs loads each webpage before doing the screenshot and it obviously takes some time, you can't speed up your web connection from python. But you can do this in parallel using e.g. `asyncio`.

Comment: I would first check the execution time of capturing and then the excecution time of saving.  If the saving is taking the bulk of the time, you might actually shave of some time by optimizing the image before saving it.